# How to add template string to a link

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

So basically what I'm wondering is if you can add a template string (this thing `${ }` ) inside of a link to change what the link is. In context, on a button click I want to generate an image with the image source being a link, but I want a text input to add to a specific part the link which would alter the image result if that makes sense. I've come up with this code but it doesn't work.

Heres my code for the button click

```
const shoesimg = document.createElement('img');
const shoesinput = document.getElementById('shoesinput');

generate.addEventListener('click', function(){

    shoesimg.src = "https://stockx-360.imgix.net//" `${shoesinput.value}` "/Images/" `${shoesinput.value}` "/Lv2/img01.jpg?auto=format,compress&w=559&q=90&dpr=2&updated_at=1580325806"
});
```

Comment: Make the whole thing a template string?

Comment: Start the whole thing with a backtick `\`` and don't include any other quotation marks, then end the whole string with another backtick `\``. It looks like you tried to combine using normal string concatenation and using templates, when really you need to just use one template. Another thing that will work is adding the concatenation symbol `+` between each string/template, but that defeats the whole purpose of using the templates.

Answer (score 0):

One example of [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
string text ${expression} string text
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make the whole link a template string.

```
const shoesimg = document.createElement('img');
const shoesinput = document.getElementById('shoesinput');

generate.addEventListener('click', function(){

    shoesimg.src = `https://stockx-360.imgix.net//${shoesinput.value}/Images/${shoesinput.value}/Lv2/img01.jpg?auto=format,compress&w=559&q=90&dpr=2&updated_at=1580325806`
});
```